# Correct existing regular expression / create a new one

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to learn Regular expressions and am trying to replace values in a string with white-spaces using regular expressions to feed it into a tokenizer. The string might contain many punctuations. However, I do not want to replace whitespaces in string which contain an apostrophe/ hyphen within them.

For example,

```
six-pack => six-pack
He's => He's
This,that => This That
```

I tried to replace all the punctuations with whitespace initially but that would not work.
I tried to replace only those punctuations by specifying the wordboundaries as in

```regex
\B[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]+\B|\b[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]+\B|\B[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]+\b
```

But, I am not able to exclude the hyphen and apostrophe from them.

My guess is that the above regex is also very cumbersome and there should be a better way. Is there any?

So, all I am trying to do is:

1. Replace all punctuations with whitespace
2. Do not do the above if they are hyphen/apostrophe
3. Do replace if the hyphen/apostrophe does occur at start/end of a word.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can probably work out a set of punctuation characters that are ok between words, and another set that isn't, then define your regular expression based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably work out a set of punctuation characters that are ok between words, and another set that isn't, then define your regular expression based on that.

For instance:

```
String[] input = {
    "six-pack",//  => six-pack
    "He's",// => He's
    "This,that"// => This That"
};
for (String s: input) {
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)[\\p{Punct}&&[^'-]](?=\\w)", " "));
}
```

**Output**

```
six-pack
He's
This that
```

**Note**

Here I'm defining the `Pattern` by using a character class including all posix for punctuation, preceded and followed by a word character, but negating a character class containing either `'` or `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```regex
(?!((?!^)['-].))\\p{Punct}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://fiddle.re/13ezq)

Comment: But , this does not address the case when the String contains punctuation character as a separate word like "This - That"

Comment: Yes OP does need to clarify this but [it works without multiline mode also](http://regex101.com/r/rB4dV3/1)

Comment: This is a case where you try to do it in a sentence

Comment: @Flash: check my demo and see if you can produce a case where this regex fails on regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative lookahead assertion like below,

```
String s = "six-pack\n"
        + "He's\n"
        + "This,that";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?m)^['-]|['-]$|(?!['-])\\p{Punct}", " "));
```

Output:

```
six-pack
He's
This that
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?m)` Multiline Mode
- `^['-]` Matches `'` or `-` which are at the start.
- `|`  OR
- `['-]$` Matches `'` or `-` which are at the end of the line.
- `|` OR
- `(?!['-])\\p{Punct}` Matches all the punctuations except these two `'` or `-` . It won't touch the  matched `[-']` symbols (ie, at the start and end).

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/rB4dV3/2)